# Furthering assistance: Volume button mod

Tags: android, button, volume

This is a suggested re-up on a question I had before. Its really and extension. So I have this code worked out to dial / call a phone number when the volume button (down) is pressed. The rest of the main code (IE: my dial / call intent works just fine) I am having a problem with the following code section:

```
    }{
    return super.onKeyLongPress(KeyEvent event);
 }}
```

The terms "KeyEvent" and "Event" are highlighted in red. Is there anyway I can get around this? when everything else has NO issues at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use as:

```
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        Log.w("myApp", "LONG PRESS");
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

see here [public boolean onKeyLongPress (int keyCode, KeyEvent event)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) method takes two arguments first `keyCode` and second `event`

Comment: As in I was implementing the log.w in the code. It did not work, or maybe I'm doing it wrong. Hmm... Lets see here.

Comment: This is not working the way I had anticipated. I'm trying to get the app to run / start up when the volume button is depressed.I sent it through to my phone but it work the way I am telling it to.

Comment: @a.kollar : as your question about terms "KeyEvent" and "Event" are highlighted in red." i give you right answer why these words are highlighted as red because you are passing wrong parameters in onKeyLongPress.so i think if you have any other issue in handling Volume up/down key post a new question.Thanks Friend !!!!:)

Comment: No the code is fine, Its just not running for some reason or another.. Alright I'll post another question.